# Сортировка списка кортежей по значению и по алфавиту в Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список:

```
[(2, 'hi'), (1, 'what'), (3, 'is'), (1, 'your'), (3, 'name'), (2, 'my'), (2, 'bond'), (1, 'james'), (4, 'damme'), (3, 'van'), (2, 'claude'), (1, 'jean')]
```

Нужно отсортировать его по значению, но если значение совпадает, то по алфавиту. Насколько я понимаю нужно передавать в `key` определенную lambda-функцию, но я не знаю как ее реализовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lst.sort(key = lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))
```

отсортирует по первому элементу туплей, с учётом второго, если первые совпадают

Результат:

```
[(1, 'james'), (1, 'jean'), (1, 'what'), (1, 'your'), 
 (2, 'bond'), (2, 'claude'), (2, 'hi'), (2, 'my'), 
 (3, 'is'), (3, 'name'), (3, 'van'), (4, 'damme')]
```

Comment: Но ведь кортеж (1, 'what') должен стоять вместо первого элемента, 'W' встречается позже 'J'.

Comment: Да, what по алфавиту стоит позже j, а не раньше. В чём несоответствие?

Comment: Нужно чтобы список был отсортирован по возрастанию и значений и, если требуется, по алфавиту начиная с конца этого алфавита, то есть должно быть так, если писать только первые буквы y, w, je, ja, my, hi и так далее

Comment: Ответ был дан на конкретный вопрос, в котором ничего не говорилось о "с конца"

Comment: l.sort(key = lambda x: (-x[0], x[1]),  reverse = True)

Comment: Да, забыл написать об этом, прошу прощения.